# Using boolean algebra laws, prove the equation, $xy+z(x'+y') = xy+z$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus, boolean-algebra

> Using the laws of Boolean algebra, prove that $xy+z(x'+y') = xy+z$

can prove it using truth table and K-map. I am yet to find a way to solve it using boolean algebra.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\begin{align}xy+z(x'+y') &=xy+z\,(xy)' &&\text{de Morgan's Rule}\\&=(xy+z)\,(xy+(xy)')&&\text{Distribution + over $\cdot$}\\&=(xy+z)\,(1)&&\text{Complement}\\&=xy+z&&\text{Identity}\end{align}$$

Comment: Don't understand why the middle step is true, you are saying $a+za' = (a+z)(a+a')$ but the RHS expands as $a^2 + az + aa' + za' = a + az + za'$ since $aa' = 0$ and $a^2=a$, but why can you just add $az$?

Comment: @gt6989b That's just the distributive law: $A+(B\cdot C) = (A+B)\cdot (A+C)$

Comment: Thank you so very much Bram28!!

Comment: @gt6989b, a + az + a'z = a (1 + z) + a'z = a + a'z

Comment: @KaushalDoshi You're welcome! :)

Comment: @KaushalDoshi thanks, this makes it very clear